# How do you make a deep copy of an object in a link list

Tags: java

hello I'm trying to make a deep copy of a linked list. basically the nodes of the links hold objects that store objects also. And I'm able to make a copy of the list container but how i can deep copy the node objects and the objects that are stored in the node.

Comment: If they are serializable, you can use an ObjectInput/output stream system to create a deep copy.

Comment: Look into `Cloneable` and `clone()`

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a [copy constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor).

Comment: could you pls show me an example. wii appreciate it.